# Vantagem e desavantagem entre onClick e setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, característica-linguagem

Tenho uma determinada situação onde vemos que é possível criar no arquivo XML uma propriedade chamada `onClick`:

### onClick:

XML:

```
<Button
android:layout_height="@dimen/edittext_min_height"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:minWidth="120sp"
android:onClick="btnSend"
android:clickable="true"/>
```

Classe:

```
public void btnSend(View view){
    //faça algo
}
```

---

Por outro lado também podemos instanciar dentro da classe o `setOnClickListener()`:

### setOnClickListener:

XML

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSend"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/edittext_min_height"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:minWidth="120sp"/>
```

Classe:

```
Button btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
btnSend .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      //faça algo
   }
});
```

Quais seriam as vantagens e desavantagens entre usar `onClick` e `setOnClickListener`?

Comment: Não tive ainda um problema real que impedisse de usar o onClick no xml. Só algumas vezes tive de usar uma mesma tela mais de uma vez no programa para situações diferentes. Talvez seja isso.

Comment: Particularmente não gosto de usar o `onClick` no XML, pois se você, por algum motivo, excluir o método `btnSend` da sua classe, não vai dar erro de **compilação**, e sim erro de **execução**.

Comment: Acredito que seja "ruim" o onClick no XML porque seria necessário criar um método para cada botão no layout, deixando o código java imenso.

Comment: Na verdade eu acho que o "android:onClick" foi implementado no android 5 essa é a única diferença.

Comment: @GabrielLocalhost julgo que o atributo `android:onClick` sempre existiu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Só encontro uma vantagem em cada uma delas que, por sua sua vez, representam uma desvantagem em relação à outra.

### `setOnClickListener()`.

- **Vantagem.**
  Permite a reutilização de código existente.
  Se implementar a interface em uma classe em separado ela pode ser reutilizada em outras situações iguais.
- **Desvantagem.**
  A implementação, sendo feita numa classe anónima, torna o código mais difícil de ler e de manter. Claro que é discutível e há quem diga o contrário. No meu entender é código que "aparece do nada", no meio daquele em que estou interessado a ler/analisar.

### `onClick`no XML

- **Vantagem.**
  Código mais fácil de ler. O código está num método declarado para esse propósito.
  Pode evitar a necessidade de ter um campo e usar o `findViewById()`
- **Desvantagem.**
  O código não pode ser reutilizado.
  Só funciona quando a *view* é usada numa Activity.

Para implementações simples e sem necessidade do código ser reutilizado, use o `onClick` no XML com o respectivo método no java.
Para implementações mais complexas e/ou reutilização do código, crie uma classe à parte e use o `setOnClickListener()`.

Comment: Se eu usar o onClick, teria como mudar dinamicamente o texto deste botão ?

Comment: Texto ou o código associado?

Comment: A duvida relacionada é: Eu só consigo alterar o texto do botão caso eu instancie usando o `findViewById()`? Se não houver alguma forma, penso talvez então ser uma desvantagem usar o `onClick` quando quero alterar o texto dos botões dinamicamente.

Comment: Não vejo qual a relação entre usar o `onClick` e alterar o texto do botão. Note que eu digo que "**Pode evitar** a necessidade de ter um atributo e usar o `findViewById()`" e não que **evita**. Penso que as (principais)razões a ter em conta para escolher uma das formas são aquelas que indico no final da resposta

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que exista apenas uma diferença ou um modo diferente de aplicação.
Os métodos são semelhantes, tanto faz você indicar a sua ação ao clicar no botão no `XML` como manusear esta ação pelo `Listener.`

Acontece que, ao utilizar o `android:onClick` o método `setOnClickListener` é implementando do mesmo jeito, só que você não o vê. Eles fazem a mesma coisa. E sim, você pode manusear várias ações diferentes utilizando o atributo no `XML.`

Veja um exemplo:

> XML

```
<Button android:id="@+id/b_1"
    android:onClick="actionHandle"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/b_2"
    android:onClick="actionHandle"/>
```

> Java

```
public void actionHandle(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.b_1:
            // act!
            break;

        case R.id.b_2:
            // act!
            break;
    }
}
```

Veja que você pode utilizar o método `actionHandle` ou qualquer método que você definir, para manusear o `click` que ocorrer em seus `botões`. Se você for utilizar o `setOnClickListener`, ficaria algo assim:

> setOnClickListener

```
public class A extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b){
        super.onCreate(b);
        // setContent

        (findViewById(R.id.b_1)).setOnClickListener(actionHandle);
        (findViewById(R.id.b_2)).setOnClickListener(actionHandle);
    }

    View.OnClickListener actionHandle= new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.b_1:

                    break;

                case R.id.b_2:

                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**Na minha opinião**, utilizar o atributo no `XML` é mais maleável e organizado e, claro, se você souber utilizar o atributo sem ficar criando vários métodos para diferentes botões, utilizar o `android:OnClick` é a melhor opção não importa o tamanho da aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Não existe um forma mais correta.

Mas a segunda opção `setOnClickListener` na `activity` é a recomendada como boas práticas.
Por possuir uma visualização mais rápida da função que o método tem.
Para realizar uma manutenção, ou mesmo durante o desenvolvimento, o uso do `onClick` no XML, pode acabar gerando um código mais confuso.

Comment: Pode explicar porque é *"a recomendada como boas práticas"*?

Comment: @ramaral Editei a resposta, mas já tinha na resposta que é para facilitar a manutenção do código, por ser mais fácil de visualizar. De qq forma, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Relendo a sua resposta fico com a ideia contrária, ou seja, parece que, quando diz *"Pois, para uma manutenção, ou mesmo durante o desenvolvimento isto acaba gerando um código mais confuso."*, se está a referir ao uso do `setOnClickListener()`.

Comment: Feito! Fiz a correção deixando claro que a segunda opção é a melhor a ser implementada. Mais uma vez, obrigado!

Comment: Sobre a afirmação "...a segunda opção é a melhor a ser implementada.". Bom, e exatamente esse o propósito da minha pergunta, saber qual vantagem e desvantagem, porém você não não indicou nenhuma referência. Você disse também "a segunda opção setOnClickListener na activity é a recomendada..." mas recomendada por quem?

Comment: @seamusd Em um aplicativo muito grande, se torna improdutivo dar manutenção nesses métodos, pois fica difícil localizar quais views que este método faz referência e vice versa.
Se o nome do método não estiver bem explícito que é um evento onClick e está sendo referenciado em um layout xml, ou não houver um comentário especificando isso, o programador poderá não saber disso até que ocorra um erro.

Comment: retirado de (http://www.brunonardini.com.br/mobile/android-boas-praticas-para-o-evento-onclick)

Comment: desculpe o link não funcionou [link](http://www.brunonardini.com.br/mobile/android-boas-praticas-para-o-evento-onclick)

Comment: *"Se o nome do método não estiver bem explícito ... "*, não é razão para não usar, porque o que está errado é o nome do método e não o uso do onClick. Tomara que todos os métodos fossem tão fáceis de dar nome como esse.

Answer (score 0):

Eu tive a mesma dúvida e dei uma aprofundada no assunto e depois [dessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184111/5654654) acabei me convencendo a não usar o onClick.
Basicamente: as implementações de botões Android indicam que o botão será clicavel, porém, se algum fabricante seta-lo para false, você só sentirá o problema através do mercado. Você pode forçar para que o botão seja clicável, porém, se esquecer, um abraço!

EDIT: Pelo que identifiquei na resposta, o problema está em setar o evento Click em um objeto não botão.

Comment: Se, como diz, "algum fabricante seta-lo para false" esse problema não terá o mesmos efeito se usar `setOnClickListener()`?

Comment: Acabei de fazer um teste bobo em um app, setei o meu  imagebutton com o clickable = false e adicionei o OnClick, ao clica-lo, tenho um erro em tempo de execução. Ao manter o clickable como false e utilizar o setonClickListener() o image funcionou normalmente.

Comment: Não consigo reproduzir qualquer erro. Tanto o `onClick` como `setOnClickListener()` funcionam. Verifique se não é o código que colocou no `onClick` que provoca o erro. O que tem de especial no uso de `android:clickable="false"` simultaneamente com `android:onClick="buttonClick"` ou `setOnClickListener()` é que o `clickable="false"` não terá efeito. Ele é colocado em `true` no método [setOnClickListener()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/view/View.java#View.setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29).