# Qual a real diferença entre essas três formas de mudar de uma activity para outra?

Tags: android, android-activity, button

Galera eu tenho conhecimento de **três formas** de que através de um simples clique em um determinado button, ele passe da activity atual para uma outra.

Gostaria de saber qual dessas três formas é a melhor levando em consideração, a fluidez do aplicativo. E se puderem, me informem um caso onde cada uma dessas três formas é preferível.

**Forma 1:**

É a forma onde eu vou lá no xml da activity e no escopo do **botão** adiciono um onClick a ele e nomeio um método. No caso: `android:onClick="addNext"`

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="genesysgeneration.twocases.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:onClick="addNext"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Feito isso, vou na MainActivity.java e só adiciono o método que especifiquei anteriormente: **addNext**.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package genesysgeneration.twocases;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void addNext(View v){

        Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(it);

    }

}
```

**Forma 2:**

Essa é a forma que eu mais utilizo, porque além de ter sido a primeira que vi, é a forma em que o código fica mais bem organizado quando a activity possui vários botões. Nela eu tenho de implementar o View.OnClickListener na "public class" dessa forma:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
```

Porém eu noto que com essa forma eu tenho de declarar também o button da activity, o que não acontece na forma que mostrei anteriormente. Nomeei o button de **btnNext**:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package genesysgeneration.twocases;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button btnNext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        Intent it = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(it);

    }

}
```

**Forma 3:**

Nela eu também tenho que declarar o button, mas a diferença é que o **Intent** é feito dentro de um método que já vem dentro do protected void onCreate e talz. Nessa forma eu também não preciso utilizar o **implements**, mas se a activity possui muitos botões, o protected void fica muito poluído:

```
package genesysgeneration.twocases;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnNext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(it);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Essas três formar que demonstrei funcionam perfeitamente, agora gostaria de saber, como já falei, a diferença entre elas.

Comment: Isso não são 3 formas de "mudar de Activity". São sim formas de implementar o *onClick*. Relacionado(duplicata?) [Vantagem e desavantagem entre onClick e setOnClickListener](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161388/2541)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Isso não são 3 formas de "mudar de Activity". São sim formas de
>   implementar o onClick @Ramaral

Considerando o que o Ramaral disse, vou explicar abaixo formas de implementar o `onClick`, de acordo com sua dúvida:

## Forma 2

[**View.OnClickListener**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)
{ public static interface View.OnClickListener }

Quando se usa `implements`, no rigor do termo, uma interface em Java nada mais é que uma classe abstrata composta somente por métodos abstratos. E como tal, obviamente não pode ser instanciada.
Ou seja, ela só contém as declarações dos métodos e constantes, nenhuma implementação, só o 'molde'.

E para que raios serve uma classe sem implementação?
Ela serve para que outras classes, baseadas nessa interface, implementem esses métodos para fins específicos.

Parece confuso e complicado, mas é como explicado sobre interface: ela será uma espécie de comunicação entre meios.
Geralmente entre o que é pedido (das funções que ela executa) e a implementação.

No Android, toda `View` possui o método `setOnClickListener`. Este método recebe como argumento qualquer objeto que possua o método `onClick(View arg0)`. Em Java, para termos certeza de que uma classe possuirá determinado método, existem as interfaces. No caso, a interface utilizada é a OnClickListener. Veja:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button btnNext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent it = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }
}
```

## **Forma 1 e Forma 3**

Especificar o atributo `android:onClick` resulta em instanciar o `Button` chamando `setOnClickListener` internamente. Portanto, não há absolutamente nenhuma diferença. Esses dois trechos de código são totalmente iguais, mas apenas implementados de duas maneiras diferentes.

### **Forma 1**

[**android:onClick**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick) {int onClick}

XML

```
<Button
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:onClick="addNext"/>
```

Main

```
public void addNext() {
    Intent it = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(it);
}
```

Isso é o suficiente para que o botão funcione. Toda vez que o usuário clicar no botão, será direcionado para uma outra *activity*. Funciona? Sim, mas…

- Se você tentar renomear (refactor) o método do evento `onClick` de forma automática, no Eclipse, ele não irá renomear o método no layout XML, quebrando o código. Se você não corrigir, o erro só daria em tempo de execução.
- Em uma aplicação muito grande, se torna improdutivo dar manutenção nesses métodos, pois fica difícil localizar quais `views` que este método faz referência e vice versa.
- Se o nome do método não estiver bem explícito que é um evento `onClick` e está sendo referenciado em um *layout* XML, ou não houver um comentário especificando isso, o programador poderá não saber disso até que ocorra um erro.

### **Forma 3**

**[setOnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)** {method public class Button}

Main

```
btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(it);

        }
});
```

### Conclusão

Em questão de performance todas as formas citadas agem de maneiras iguais, possuindo exatamente o mesmo comportamento. Porém existem facilidades características entre uma e outra que dependerá do projeto em que será usado. Veja mais sobre [Vantagem e desavantagem entre onClick e setOnClickListener](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161388/vantagem-e-desavantagem-entre-onclick-e-setonclicklistener) e também este artigo sobre [Cinco maneiras diferentes de usar o *Event Listener*](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=2359#1._Member_Class)<sup>(en)</sup>.

#### Referências

- [Classe Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)
- [View.OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)
- [Interface em Java](http://www.javaprogressivo.net/2012/10/Interface-em-Java-implements-O-que-e-para-que-serve-como-funciona.html)

Answer (score 2):

A forma 2 e 3 são a mesma coisa. OnClick é um método de uma interface de callback.

Fazendo isso daqui:

```
new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }
}
```

Você está instanciando a interface OnClickListener da Classe View e está implementando o método `onClick(View v)`;

E logo depois, setando ela com um famoso método set:

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(View.onClicListener onClickListener);
```

A forma 2 não é uma forma interessante quando você tem duas Views que possuem comportamentos diferentes em um Click.

A forma 1 é só uma outra maneira que a Google te dá de fazer a mesma coisa da forma 2. Não existe nenhuma diferença de performance.

Eu prefiro usar a forma dois. A maior parte da literatura que você encontrar por ai vai utilizar o onClick assim.

> o Intent é feito dentro de um método que já vem dentro do protected
>   void onCreate e talz.

Essa frase está muito errada. O método onClick não "já vem dentro" de outro método, como expliquei antes, é um método de uma interface.

Eu te aconselho fortemente a estudar interface de callback, conhecido também como Listeners. É muito usado, não só em interfaces gráficas. Fazendo uso dessas interfaces, você diminui muito o acoplamento das classes, ainda mais quando se faz bibliotecas que vão ser usadas por terceiros.