# Android Studio: Problema invisivel?

Tags: android, android-studio

Olá, estou a fazer uma app para calcular a melhor compra entre 2 produtos, neste caso é papel higiénico.

No título pus problema invisivel porque o android studio 3 não deteta nenhum erro na compilação, no entanto, quando executo a aplicação, quando clico no botão comparar a aplicação dá erro e pede para ser reiniciada, sem explicar onde está o erro. Deixo aqui os códigos para ver se alguém me pode ajudar, pois não encontro o erro, nem o android studio, lool

Ficheiro xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="420dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="Comparar 2 preços de papel higienico para saber qual é o mais barato. Preencha os dados e clique no botão Comparar!"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editPrecoA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Preço"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editPrecoA"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editPrecoA"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:text="Papel Higiénico A"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editRolosA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editPrecoA"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editPrecoA"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editPrecoA"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editPrecoA"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editPrecoA"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Nº Rolos"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editMetrosA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editRolosA"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editRolosA"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editRolosA"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editRolosA"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editRolosA"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Metros por rolo"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editPrecoB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editPrecoA"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editPrecoA"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Preço"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editPrecoB"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editPrecoB"
    android:text="Papel Higiénico B"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editRolosB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editPrecoB"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editPrecoB"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editPrecoB"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Nº Rolos"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editMetrosB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editRolosB"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editRolosB"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editRolosB"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Metros por rolo"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textResultadoB"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:onClick="calcular_produtos"
    android:text="Comparar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textResultadoA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editMetrosA"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editMetrosA"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="....." />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textResultadoB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editMetrosB"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editMetrosB"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textResultadoA"
    android:text="....." />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textResultadoFinal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
    android:text="....." />
```

Agora o ficheiro da class

```
package com.blogspot.comprasinteligentes;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editPrecoA, editPrecoB, editRolosA, editRolosB, editMetrosA, editMetrosB;
    TextView textResultadoA, textResultadoB, textResultadoFinal;
    Button button;

    Double NumRolosA, NumRolosB, TotalMetrosA, TotalMetrosB, NumMetrosA, NumMetrosB, ValorPorMetroA, ValorPorMetroB, PrecoA, PrecoB, Dif, Poupanca;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        //Procura os valores dos objetos
        editPrecoA = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPrecoA);
        editPrecoB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPrecoB);

        editRolosA = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editRolosA);
        editRolosB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editRolosB);

        editMetrosA = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editMetrosA);
        editMetrosB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editMetrosB);

        textResultadoA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResultadoA);
        textResultadoA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResultadoB);
        textResultadoFinal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResultadoFinal);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            //Ao clicar em Comparar então vai calcular o produto mais barato
             // Contas ==========================================
             // TotalMetros = NºRolos x Metros por rolo
             // ValorPorMetro = Preco / TotalMetros

             // Dif = ValorPorMetroA - ValorPorMetroB

             // Poupança = Did x TotalMetros

             //================================================

                NumRolosA = Double.parseDouble(editRolosA.getText().toString());
                NumMetrosA = Double.parseDouble(editMetrosA.getText().toString());

                TotalMetrosA = NumRolosA * NumMetrosA;

                NumRolosB = Double.parseDouble(editRolosB.getText().toString());
                NumMetrosB = Double.parseDouble(editMetrosB.getText().toString());

                TotalMetrosB = NumRolosB * NumMetrosB;

               PrecoA = Double.parseDouble(editPrecoA.getText().toString());
               ValorPorMetroA = PrecoA / TotalMetrosA;

                PrecoB = Double.parseDouble(editPrecoB.getText().toString());
                ValorPorMetroB = PrecoB / TotalMetrosB;



             if (ValorPorMetroA > ValorPorMetroB) {
                 Dif = ValorPorMetroA - ValorPorMetroB;
                 Poupanca = Dif * TotalMetrosB;

                 //Mostra resultados
                 textResultadoFinal.setText("Vencedor: Papel Higiénico A\nPoupa nesta embalagem: " + String.valueOf(Poupanca));
             }

             if (ValorPorMetroA < ValorPorMetroB) {
                 Dif = ValorPorMetroB - ValorPorMetroA;
                 Poupanca = Dif * TotalMetrosA;

                 //Mostra resultado
                 textResultadoFinal.setText("Vencedor: Papel Higiénico B\nPoupa nesta embalagem: " + String.valueOf(Poupanca));
             }

             if (ValorPorMetroA == ValorPorMetroB) {
                 Dif = ValorPorMetroA - ValorPorMetroB;
                 Poupanca = Dif * TotalMetrosA;

                 textResultadoFinal.setText("Vencedor: Ambos custam o mesmo!");
             }

             textResultadoA.setText("Preço por metro: " + String.valueOf(ValorPorMetroA));
             textResultadoB.setText("Preço por metro: " + String.valueOf(ValorPorMetroB));
            }

     });

    }
```

Comment: Cara, é IMPOSSÍVEL não ter um LogCat com o erro, mas eu acredito que no TextView com ID **editPrecoA** tem um **android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"** sendo que o **textView3** nem foi criado ainda

Comment: Olá, passei o editPrecoA para baixo do textView3, no entanto, não funciona. O programa diz que sofreu uma falha de sistema.

Comment: Olá! ver o erro no LogCat [veja esse link](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html?hl=pt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você errou aqui:

```
textResultadoA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResultadoA);
textResultadoA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResultadoB);
textResultadoFinal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResultadoFinal);
```

Tem 2 `textResultadoA`

Correto:

```
textResultadoA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResultadoA);
textResultadoB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResultadoB);
textResultadoFinal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResultadoFinal);
```

Comment: Grande Amigo! Funciona! Você descobriu a agulha no palheiro!
Obrigado por ver esta falha que me escapou, nem sei como (talvez do copiar e colar).

Comment: Opa, estamos aí ! Não esqueça de ver a forma que o ramaral passou !

Comment: A minha resposta estava errada.

Comment: Estava ? Você só passou como usar com public ao invés de fazer no onCreate não foi ?

Comment: @CelestinoXP não esqueça de marcar como resolvida.

Comment: A minha resposta partia do principio errado de que se o atributo `android:onClick` é usado ele tem de ser implementado. O que não é verdade se se usar o `setOnClickListener()`.

Comment: Ah entendi... é que de costume uso tudo o máximo fora do onCreate, para de pois conseguir manipular as propriedades, ações, etc dos elementos.

Comment: Veja [Vantagem e desavantagem entre onClick e setOnClickListener](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/161388/2541)

Comment: Opa ! Vou ver ! Valeu @ramaral ! Obrigado

Comment: @RaoniBZ como faço para marcar como resolvida?

Comment: Ao lado da resposta tem um "V". Clica nele que ficará verde.