# Como chamar um Metodo na View usando uma Class que estende de Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tenho vários botões em uma view que chamam o método addNumero no Onclick, mais ou menos assim:

```
<Button
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:onClick="addNumero"
  android:text="8" />
```

E como são muitos botões, fica inviável usar o `setOnClickListener` em cada um.
Tenho uma class que herda de fragment: `public class Exemplo extends Fragment` e est class infla a view que contém os botões e nessa class também está o método `addNumero` mas  não está funcionando, quando eu clico não chama o addNumero.

Comment: O uso de `android:onClick` só funciona quando a *view* é usada numa Activity.

Comment: Então, mas a minha view é usada em uma Fragment, esse é o problema

Comment: Como o `android:onClick` não funciona em um Fragment tem obrigatoriamente de usar `setOnClickListener()`.

Answer (score 1):

O atributo `onClick` só funciona quando a view está sendo usada numa Activity, você vai ter que implementar um `View.OnClickListener`.

Se você tem muitos botões na tela com funções semelhantes, pode criar uma só classe para usar como Listener.

`private class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener`

Se os botões tiverem funções diferentes, crie várias classes em arquivos separados, assim, mesmo com muito código, tudo vai estar organizado.

Fontes:

https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/305

https://hackernoon.com/4-ways-to-implement-onclicklistener-on-android-9b956cbd2928

EDIT: resposta esclarecida com a ajuda do https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2541/ramaral

Comment: *"Não é recomendável usar onClick no xml, esse arquivo deve representar apenas o visual, não chamar funções."* Porquê? Isso é o equivalente ao `setOnClickListener()`, apenas limita a que o método exista na *activity*. Por outro lado se *"esse arquivo deve representar apenas o visual, não chamar funções."*, então qualquer tipo de "binding" seria também *"Não recomendável"*.

Comment: A questão de não chamar funções no xml é uma questão conceitual de MVC, onde o View e o Controller devem ficar separados.

Comment: Sim, isso é verdade, mas o que aqui está em causa não tem nada haver com isso. O método atribuído no `android:onClick` apenas tem de chamar um outro no Controller. O que deve ficar separado é a implementação e caso esta envolva o Model. Acções que não envolvam o Model, que apenas tenham efeito na UI, não devem ser implementadas no Controller.

Comment: Você tem razão, mas, como você mesmo colocou no comentário da pergunta, o onClick só funciona quando a view é usada numa Activity, então minha resposta ainda é válida, vou editar para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Talvez não me tenha explicado bem. O que quero dizer é que você não utilizará/implementará a interface View.OnClickListener no Controller. Ou seja, em termos de MVC, tanto faz usar `android:onClick` ou `setOnClickListener()`, o método `onClick()` não será implementado/usado no Controller.

Comment: Eu entendi, não tinha pensado dessa forma.

Comment: Veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/161429/2541) o que eu penso entre usar `android:onClick` ou `setOnClickListener()`

Comment: @ramaral, A class MyClickListener eu faço por fora, ou eu implemento o View.OnClickListener na própria Class onde eu estou trabalhando com os botões? E caso eu chame por fora, como eu uso ela dentro da Classe que estou trabalhando?  Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Se fizer uma classe MyClickListener é ela que implementa o View.OnClickListener. Para usar na classe em que está a trabalhar(Fragment) faça `aSuaView.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListene())`.